# Primefaces in intranet site in IE error: SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1 for the front-end components in my current Java Web application. Everything is okay in all browsers.

However, when I tried to visit the application through an **intranet** website which is running on only IE, "Primefaces Paging" hasn't been working and I encountered a Javascript Error which is "SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101."

I have tried many solutions that is suggested here and in other forums but I couldn't be successful.

Windows 7, IE 11, PrimeFaces 5.1.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: https://www.ascadnetworks.com/Guides-and-Tips/IE-error-%2522Could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-80020101%2522

Comment: I tried these solutions, too but they didn't work. By the way, I have no  custum javascript file. I am just using primefaces' and jquery's js files. The error occurs in  one of the ajax methods in jquery.js file(25,91234)